# Java Server Data Storage what is the best strategy?

Tags: java, storage

I am developing a Gameserver, since i have to store the progress of every player, i have the question:
What it the best data Storage solution for my case?

Some facts:
At the moment, every Player is a Row in my MYsql-Database, having a unique id and name.
Every player has a World.
Every world contains a growing set of regions (as the player moves forward).
And every Region contains a set of landscapes.
Here comes the problem.

I want to add new landscapes as easy as possible, so i have this simple concept:
i have an interface landscape.java containing only one method called doit(String command)
Every implementation of a landscape is doing fancy stuff in their doit-methods without me having to change any code.

Now i have to store the world of every player, here are some ideas/options i thought of

- Storing everythin in a database would require me to create tables for every implementation of a landscape. would be a bad solution imo
- Serialisation was another idea, perfect because i do not have to worry about anything simply cast to landscape and fine. But i have my doubts, how should i edit the data, whats to do when i update the classes, how do i roll out changes to the data.
- Frameworks like Hibernate, JPA etc. (i have no deep knowledge in them, could this be helpfull in my case?)
- Writing my own file-format, changes in my strategie or other ideas?

Some perhaps inportant information at the end:

- Saved data has to be editable
- storing is not time-critical and should be done in normal time
- Since all data is cached in memory, i do not really care about it being fast, it more likely has to be reliable
- possible to use are PostgreSQL/Mysql and Filesystem.

I am not experienced in this field, so please give me a hint if i'm going a wrong way ;)

Comment: What about an object database like [db4o](http://www.db4o.com/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anything which suggest you should chose one approach over another.

Some people will have a preference and I would go with whatever you prefer.

If you are going to Serialize your data, I would use a Text Serialization which makes it easy to edit it in a text editor. e.g. XML, JSon, CSV.

Comment: XML-Serialisation is a good idea!
I will give X-Stream a try, storing it into a MySQL-Blob.
Thanks!

Comment: X-Stream also support JSon so you can try both outputs and see which you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

This all sounds sufficiently vague that I would just select one solution and try it.

Make sure your code is *sufficiently abstracted* from it such that you can replace it at a later date with a new solution. Lots of projects migrate through solutions through their lifetime (as requirements and scale change) and the key is to try and ensure that it causes you as little disruption as possible.